# SQL merging records based on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, merge, date-range

I have a data set representing deliveries made by several vehicles, which can each load and discharge at different locations. I am trying to find out how many vehicles it took to do all deliveries, while grouping/merging all trips that loaded within +- x days. For example:

- vehicle V1 could load in Zone A (date X) and B (date X+2), and discharge in Zone C and D, that would count as 1 vehicle/trip because it loaded within 2 days.
- V1 could also simply do Zone A (date Y) to Zone C, that would count 1 trip as well

This is how the raw data looks like:

```
    Id  LoadArea    LoadDate    Vehicle Discharge Area  Qty
456559  Zone A      15/07/2019   V1     Zone Z          64
408481  Zone B      13/07/2019   V1     Zone X          70
365566  Zone A      12/07/2019   V1     Zone Y          26
244634  Zone C      12/07/2019   V2     Zone X          10
453409  Zone D      10/07/2019   V2     Zone Z          53
183776  Zone A      20/04/2019   V1     Zone Y          13
379698  Zone A      20/04/2019   V1     Zone Z          21
370324  Zone D      28/02/2019   V3     Zone W          39
```

This is what I am aiming to get to:

```
LoadArea        LoadDate    Vehicle Qty
Zone A;Zone B   12/07/2019  V1          160
Zone C;ZoneD    10/07/2019  V2          63
Zone A;Zone B   20/04/2019  V1          34
Zone D          28/02/2019  V3          39
```

The LoadDate returned when merging records that are less than +- X days away would ideally be the earliest one of the records being merged.

Would anyone have an idea how to do this - i've been stuck on this for days now.... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what database are you using sql server/oracle/postgresql

Comment: I'm using SQL Server - sorry about that