# Group Records based on predefined date range in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, date-range, oracle18c

Is it possible to group records based on a predefined date range differences (e.g. 30 days) based on the `start_date` of a row and the `end_date` of the previous row for non-consecutive dates?  I want to take the `min(start_date)` and `max(end_date)` of each group. I tried the `lead` and `lag` function with partition by in Oracle but couldn't come up with a proper solution. A related but unanswered post related to my question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059123/sql-merging-records-based-on-date-range).

E.g.

```
ROW_NUM        PROJECT_ID       START_DATE       END_DATE          
1              1                2016-01-14       2016-08-15
2              1                2016-08-16       2016-09-10     --- Date diff Row 1&2 = 1 Day
3              1                2016-11-15       2017-01-10     --- Date diff Row 2&3  = 66 Days
4              1                2016-01-17       2017-04-10     --- Date diff Row 3&4 = 7 Days
5              2                2018-04-28       2018-06-01     --- Other Project
6              2                2019-02-01       2019-04-05     --- Diff > 30 Days
7              2                2019-04-08       2019-07-28     --- Diff 3 Days
```

Expected Result:

```
ROW_NUM        PROJECT_ID       START_DATE       END_DATE          
1              1                2016-01-14       2016-09-10
3              1                2016-11-15       2017-04-10     
5              2                2018-04-28       2018-06-01   
6              2                2019-02-01       2019-07-28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()` and a cumulative sum to define where the groups begin.  Then aggregate:

```
select project_id, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date > start_date - interval '30' day then 0 else 1 end) over
                  (partition by project_id order by start_date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (partition by project_id order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by project_id, grp;
```